# Apache/nginx are running but browser show connection failure

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, redhat

I have just installed nginx and apache on a dedicated server with redhat, how ever when I go to http://65.111.167.39 I get a connection failure. 
I tried changing nginx port con conf, but it didn't work neither.

Both services are running:

/etc/init.d/httpd status
httpd (pid  22498) is running...

/etc/init.d/nginx status
nginx (pid  22534) is running...

Some advices?
By the way I have no experience at all, so anything could be missing..

Comment: Define "doesn't show anything"? A blank page? A 404 page? A connection failure?

Comment: ceejayoz I have edited the post. Thankyou.

Comment: does netstat or lsof -i show you the process listening on port 80 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check if the default firewall is running:

iptables -nL

Sounds simple but I've seen many people run in circles before remembering to check this.

Run a netstat so you can be sure the service is actually bound to the port.

Note that you cannot bind both nginx and apache to the same port.

Comment: using "service iptables stop" worked both ports (nginx and apache) now I'll read about iptables to learn how to use them correctly. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Also check /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny

Try and connect from the redhat box http://127.0.0.1. If you only have a shell you can use lynx or links.

Comment: this also helped me, http://127.0.0.1 showed the page correctly.